# 0/1 Knapsack Problem with Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is my attempt at the problem asked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642912/using-dynamic-programming-to-solve-a-version-of-the-knapsack-problem). When I try to run it with input `egg_weights = (1,5,10,25)` and `n = 99`, it seems to run into an infinite loop. The code seems to give the correct answer for smaller `n`, albeit very slowly. What went wrong here?

```
def dp_make_weight(egg_weights, target_weight, memo = {}):
    if target_weight < 0:
        return float('inf')
    elif target_weight == 0:
        return 0
    elif target_weight > 0:
        try:
            return memo[target_weight]
        except:
            memo[target_weight] = float('inf')
            for weight in egg_weights:
                result = dp_make_weight(egg_weights, target_weight - weight, memo = {})
                if result < memo[target_weight]:
                    memo[target_weight] = result + 1
        return result + 1
```

Here's the code that was provided for testing purpose.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    egg_weights = (1, 5, 10, 25)
    n = 99
    print("Egg weights = (1, 5, 10, 25)")
    print("n = 99")
    print("Expected ouput: 9 (3 * 25 + 2 * 10 + 4 * 1 = 99)")
    print("Actual output:", dp_make_weight(egg_weights, n))
    print()
```

Comment: In your recursive call you don't reuse the same memo map, which looks dubious to me

Comment: Also the default argument `{}` is questionable, since subsequent calls will pick up the same dict, even if the egg_weights list has changed.

Comment: Please provide full code you are using to test your solution. There are some specifics to this code that depend on the way you are calling it.

Comment: @TomKarzes I thought that was the idea? There's just one variable memo for every call. What I was trying to do is that, at a given step where target_weight > 0, the algorithm explores every possible option (that's why I have (target_weight - weight) for every given weight in the recursive call). The memo's supposed to be a shortcut, in the sense that at every call, the algorithm check if memo[target_weight] exists. If it does, then retrieve it as the best possible option from the given node. If not, then compute that value and store it in the memo.

Comment: @TomKarzes It is by design that "subsequent calls will pick up the same dict,". The caller is not meant to override the *memo* argument, which, as a cache, should always be the identical `dict`. This is a very useful idiom. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221224620id_/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Comment: If you are using argument *memo* as a computed value cache, you should not explicitly pass it as an argument to `dp_make_weight`. Instead you should always rely on using the mutable default value and in that way there is only a single cache used for all calls to this function.

Comment: @Booboo No, you don't understand.  If a different `egg_weights` argument is given, the function will give incorrect results.  I explained all of this in my first comment, but I guess you didn't understand.  The `memo` values are specific to a given `egg_weights` list.  Look at the keys.  They only contain the remaining target weight.  Therefore, the dict only works for a *single* `egg_weights` list.

Comment: @ensbana Read my original comment again, and the one above.  It is true that you want to reuse the `memo` dict, but *only* for the same `egg_weights` list.  If a different `egg_weights` list is given, then the results will be incorrect if the same `memo` dict is used.  And even in the case where the function calls itself recursively, with the same `egg_weights` list, your own code fails to use the same `memo` dict, instead passing a *new* empty one (which is just a bug).

Comment: @TomKarzes I get that but it wasn't clear from the posted code that `dp_make_weight` was going to be called for different egg weight lists. See my posted answer.

Comment: @Booboo Any function that can only be called a second time if one of the arguments is identical to what it was the first time it was called is a broken function.  The right way to code something like that in Python is to make it a class, which is initialized with a specific set of egg weights.  It can then provide a method which can be called multiple times with different target weights, but which uses the same set of egg weights each time.  If a different set of egg weights is desired, then a new class instance is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to call `dp_make_weight` for different egg weight lists, then the default *memo* argument should be handled as follows. Also, read my comments in the code:

```py
def dp_make_weight(egg_weights, target_weight, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}

    infinity = float('inf')

    if target_weight < 0:
        return float('inf')
    elif target_weight == 0:
        return 0
    else: # target_weight must be > 0
        if target_weight in memo:
            return memo[target_weight]
        result = infinity
        for weight in egg_weights:
            # Only update result when dp_make_weight returns a value smaller than
            # the current result value. Also note that the current value of memo
            # is what is being passed and not a new, empty dict:
            new_result = dp_make_weight(egg_weights, target_weight - weight, memo)
            if new_result < result:
                result = new_result
        result += 1
        memo[target_weight] = result
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    egg_weights = (1, 5, 10, 25)
    n = 99
    print("Egg weights =", egg_weights)
    print("n =", n)
    print("Expected ouput: 9 (3 * 25 + 2 * 10 + 4 * 1 = 99)")
    print("Actual output:", dp_make_weight(egg_weights, n))

    print()

    egg_weights = (1, 6, 9, 12, 13, 15)
    n = 724
    print("Egg weights =", egg_weights)
    print("n =", n)
    print("Expected ouput: 49")
    print("Actual output:", dp_make_weight(egg_weights, n))
```

Prints:

```
Egg weights = (1, 5, 10, 25)
n = 99
Expected ouput: 9 (3 * 25 + 2 * 10 + 4 * 1 = 99)
Actual output: 9

Egg weights = (1, 6, 9, 12, 13, 15)
n = 724
Expected ouput: 49
Actual output: 49
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's that 'memo = {}' bit in the recursive calls that really messed up my code.

Comment: Not just that but having defined the *memo* argument to `dp_make_weight` as `memo={}` would cause you to reuse the same memo cache for different egg weights. Defining a default value that is a mutable object that gets modified in the function is the problem because the same *identical* object will be used as the default the next time the function is called without overriding the default value.